# How can I check if my server is allowed to access another server through a specific port?

Tags: port, connection, timeout

My server: Windows Server 2003.
Their server: probably the same thing... it's running active directory LDAP over there...

Problem is when attempting to connect to LDAPS over a secure port, it just times out. However it works totally fine on my QA server (server A) but on live production server (server B) it just times out. I have set everything up the same on both servers... They said they have allowed both of my servers through their firewall over the specific port, however it only works on one of them, thus I know it is not my code failing but some other issue... because like I said, it works fine on QA but fails on Live...

is there anything I can run to check why it would be timing out from the live server? I tried ping and tracert and the effects are the same on both servers, it responds fine... however when trying to add the port number to these commands i just get an error, is there a similar command that will test the port?

thanks..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A very basic check you can try is to telnet to the port, if it times out then it's inaccessible, if you get a clear screen and flashing cursor (it may timeout with and error eventually or possibly even print some text), just type "TELNET {IP Address} {PORT}".

Answer (score 2):

To add to Chopper3's answer, there is also a program called [nmap](http://www.nmap.org/) that would come in handy for this. There is a nice windows version. You should be able to type nmap and then the IP address and it will scan for open ports on the given ip.

Comment: Not as a criticism of this answer, but as a warning:  Some administrators view nmap scans as threatening, and some IDSes or firewalls view this activity as malicious and act to block all communication from the external host.  You should let the admin of the remote host know before you start an nmap scan.